# Java Linked List of Objects. How can I keep count of each unique object?

Tags: java, object

I was working on implementing a Linked List of Flowers. I've been successful in getting the program to do what I want it to do. I can display the contents of the list, the attributes of each node's object, and I can do other things to the list. However, what if I want to display only the unique occurrences of each object and the count?

So for example, say I add 2 Rose objects and 1 Daffodil object to the list. If I display the contents with my current method, it displays each object on its own line in the console. But I want to develop a new find method that displays something like :

```
There are  2 occurrences of Rose!
There are 1 occurrences of Daffodil!
```

With my current code, this won't work. I get:

```
There is a Rose!
There is a Rose!
There is a Daffodil!
```

Here is the experimental find2 method I've worked on thus far:

```
public void find2(String searchName){
    Node theNode = firstNode;
    int occurrences = 0;

    if(!isEmpty()){
        while (theNode.getItem().getName() != searchName){
            if (theNode.getItem().getName().equals(searchName)){
                occurrences++;
            }
            else if (theNode.getNext() == null){
                System.out.println("Flower not found!");
                return;
            }

            theNode = theNode.getNext();

        }

        System.out.println("Found " + occurrences + " occurrences of " + searchName + ".");
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with the logic? I've tried adding a second condition to the else if. It was:

```
else if (theNode.getNext() == null && occurrences == 0){
    System.out.println("Flower not found!");
    return null;
}
```

However that didn't help either. What happens when I run the program is that, depending on how I've tinkered with the method, I'll input the name I want to search for and it'll stall - in other words, the console lets me input more stuff but it doesn't do anything with it. Or it'll give me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at LinkedList.find2(LinkedList.java:69)
    at FinalProject.searchFlowers(FinalProject.java:81)
    at FinalProject.<init>(FinalProject.java:37)
    at FinalProject.main(FinalProject.java:10)
```

If you would like to see all of the code, I can provide it. I appreciate any hints or suggestions! Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: If you compare strings with `.equals`, does it fix the problem?

Comment: I tried it earlier but it didn't work. Someone posted a solution that works perfectly but then he deleted it.

Comment: The behavior of a unique ordered collection of items could be found in the [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) - I am aware you are designing your own type, so this may just be superflous but I wanted to point out its existance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First test for null, before you test for equality!

```
while (theNode.getItem().getName() != searchName) { // <-- NO!
  if (theNode.getItem().getName().equals(searchName)) { // <-- B
    occurrences++;
  } else if (theNode.getNext() == null){ // <-- A
    System.out.println("Flower not found!");
    return;
  }
  theNode = theNode.getNext();
}
```

I believe you wanted something like this

```
while (theNode != null) { // <-- null test.
  if (theNode.getItem().getName().equals(searchName)){ // <-- B
    occurrences++;
  } else { //theNode.getItem().getName() != searchName
    break;
  }
  theNode = theNode.getNext();
}
if (occurrences == 0) { // <-- A
  System.out.println("Flower not found!");
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
         while(theNode.getNext()!=null)
          {
            if(theNode.getNext().getName().equals(searchName))
            {
               occurrences++;
            }
         }
         if(occurences==0)
          { 
            System.out.println("Flower not Found");
          }
         else
          {
            System.out.println("Found items "+seachname+""+occurences);
          }
```